# How to get badge "Unsung Hero"?

Tags: support, badges

The [Unsung Hero](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/badges/51/unsung-hero) badge staed:

> Zero score accepted answers: more than 10 and 25% of total

How to get this badge?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get that badge when you provided answers that have been accepted, but the score of those answers is zero. (The score is the difference between up-votes and down-votes.)

When those answers are more than 10, and 25% of all the answers you gave, then you get the badge.